# Automatic data sharing between Google Docs files

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-slides

Is it possible to automatically update information on a Google Presentation or Document based on information in a Google spreadsheet?

For example, I could create a presentation that contains a graph based on data in a spreadsheet. As the spreadsheet is updated, the graph on the presentation is automatically updated.